# Difficulty understanding using Threshold for Facial Recognition

Tags: face-recognition, threshold

This is an understanding based question for using a threshold approach for facial recognition. I understand in laymans terms how we can identify faces with threshold using the following steps:

1. Form eigenspace using top k eigenfaces
2. Project Training faces on the eigenspace
3. Project the test face on the eigenspace
4. Calculate distance between the test face and training faces in the eigenspace
5. Select the closest training face to the testing face
6. Check whether the distance passes the recognition threshold

I understand the process all up until step 6. I gathered that the threshold is the percentage of data that is kept, however I dont understand why we would change this value. ie. why we would make it smaller/bigger, and how do we know what we should make this value? 
Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You honestly think a description that uses the word "eigenspace" would be understood by the typical layman?   Also, this is not really a software concern, so is technically off-topic.

The concept of what you're asking about is described by "Detection Theory".

The basics of detection theory involves a sensor system that does measurements.  Those measurements are of some disturbance of the environment.   In an ideal world, the measurement would be some constant unless something of interest is actually present.   The real world is not that kind though.   In the real world, there are disturbances that will be measured (called noise or background) even if nothing of interest is present, and those measurements will have some distribution.   If something is present, the disturbance it causes is superimposed on the background, and the measurement is the total of the two (generally with no way to tell them apart).

So, when our sensor does a measurement, some decision criterion is needed to decide if there is actually something of interest present.   Usually, the measurements are expressed in terms of numerical values (either directly, or after processing).  A common criterion for calling a detection (or a match when doing facial recognition) is to calculate some numerical measure and call a detection when the measured value exceeds some other chosen value - the threshold.

Every threshold is associated with four conditional probabilities:  probability of detection or true positive (calling a match when there is something present to match), probability of false alarm (calling a match when there is nothing present to match), probability of false negative (not calling something present when something is present), and true negative (not calling something present when nothing is present).

The probabilities depend on the background distribution and on the distribution of actual disturbances of interest.   In an ideal world, we would always make the right call  i.e. probability of detection would be 100%, probability of a true negative is 100%, probability of false alarm or false negative would be zero.   The real world is not that kind, so the probabilities we want would not be 100%, and the probabilities we don't want would be non-zero.

Change the threshold, and all the probabilities change (in a way determined by the distributions).   Usually thresholds are specified in terms of an associated probability of detection and a probability of false alarm (with those two bits of information, and some model specifying the distributions, it is possible to derive the other probabilities).   For example, a threshold may be chosen to give a probability of detection of 90% (i.e. if a disturbance is actually present, we have a 90% chance of correctly calling it) with a false alarm rate of 10^-6 (if we call a detection, there is one chance in a million of there not actually being something of interest).    On the other hand, if we're willing to accept missing half of all detections for the same false alarm rate, we would use a lower threshold.

The choice of probability of detection and false alarm rate is important, but it is a balancing act.   Make the probability of detection too low, and we miss too many occurrences (e.g. X% of baddies not being recognised every day).    Make the false alarm rate too high, and we get too many false hits (e.g. one false hit a second versus one false hit a day) - which is expensive because every false alarm has to be investigated by other means.